# Call a global variable inside module

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript file called `Projects.ts` that I want to reference a global variable declared in a bootstrap plugin called `bootbox.js`.

I want to access a variable called `bootbox` from within a TypeScript classes.

Is it possible?

Comment: There is a DefinitelyTyped definition for bootbox now https://www.nuget.org/packages/bootbox.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764468/reference-to-global-variable-from-a-module

Comment: The correct answer is the comment from ThisGuy above and the answer from @ser-savv below https://stackoverflow.com/a/49406280/1450483

Answer (score 458):

You need to tell the compiler it has been declared:

```
declare var bootbox: any;
```

If you have better type information you can add that too, in place of `any`.

Comment: Can skip ': any' bit actually.

Comment: That wouldn't make a good example for a Q&A format though as I am suggesting they do add specific type information and the answer shows how and where they would put it.

Comment: For us typescript newbies, where do we put that `declare` statement?

Comment: Is this a good solution for global functions too? Placing something like `declare var myFunction: any;`?

Comment: @jonathanrz yes, it can be a specific signature too if you want to go that far, for example `declare var myFunction: (input: string) => void;`

Comment: Still can't get access to global variable in a module. Do I need to `export` global var from main file and `import` it in any module I need it? Why do we need `declare` in this case?

Comment: @TotalAMD within modules you can use `declare global { ... }` and pop your `var` in there.

Answer (score 59):

For those who didn't know already, you would have to put the `declare` statement outside your `class` just like this:

```
declare var Chart: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss']
})

export class MyComponent {
    //you can use Chart now and compiler wont complain
    private color = Chart.color;
}
```

In `TypeScript` the declare keyword is used where you want to define a variable that may not have originated from a `TypeScript` file.

It is like you tell the compiler that, I know this variable will have a value at runtime, so don't throw a compilation error.

Answer (score 20):

If it is something that you reference but never mutate, then use `const`:

```
declare const bootbox;
```

Answer (score 15):

Sohnee solutions is cleaner, but you can also try

```
window["bootbox"]
```

Answer (score 12):

If You want to have a reference to this variable across the whole project, create somewhere `d.ts` file, e.g. `globals.d.ts`. Fill it with your global variables declarations, e.g.:

```
declare const BootBox: 'boot' | 'box';
```

Now you can reference it anywhere across the project, just like that:

```
const bootbox = BootBox;
```

Here's an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dwcfd5).

Comment: Your linked StackBlitz gives `Error: BootBox is not defined`

Answer (score 3):

```js
// global.d.ts
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      bootbox: string; // Specify ur type here,use `string` for brief
    }
  }
}

// somewhere else
const bootbox = global.bootbox
// somewhere else
global.bootbox = 'boom'
```

Answer (score -3):

Download the [bootbox typings](https://www.nuget.org/packages/bootbox.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/)

Then add a reference to it inside your .ts file.

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: Wow, this is definitely the correct answer. Unbelievable to see it down here at the bottom in the negative points. Unlike the other answers manually declaring `bootbox` as `any`, this will correctly type the `bootbox` global so that properties on it are understood correctly by TypeScript.

And this is true generally for other libraries. You can often find the type definition and import it. That is the proper way to do it.