# Reference to global variable from a module

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a global variable declared in the html header and want to reference it from a class inside a module. How can I prevent compiler error:

**error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'selfGlobal'.**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        var selfGlobal = this;
        var globalVariable = 1;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>   
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In test.ts

```
module Test{
    export class TestClass {
        private _privateVariable:any; 
        constructor() {
            this._privateVariable = selfGlobal.globalVariable; // compile error throws here, but the code can run

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!
Mars

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252225/call-a-global-variable-inside-typescript-module

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler it has been declared:

```
declare var selfGlobal: any;
```

Comment: Might as well be `declare var selfGlobal:Window;` :)

Comment: Thank you it works.  I got a compiler error against globalVariable, but it disappears after I declare globalVariable as well.