# Use a variable from ancestor module when it's declared elsewhere

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here's my situation. I have some legacy vanilla JavaScript loaded that contains this code:

```javascript
window.A = { x: { /* several things live here */ } };
```

This is the minimal code to repro my problem. In reality `A` is our global "namespace" object, and `x` is an object with some legacy functions I want to access in my newer Typescript classes.

So, after the above has run, I'm trying to access `x` inside a class in a nested Typescript module, like this:

```javascript
module A {       
    module B {
        export class Item {
            constructor(){
                alert(A.x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Web Essesntials as well as the typescriptlang.org site can generate JavaScript which will in fact work as required, but VS2012' respectively typescriptlang.org's syntax highlighting both complain that:

> Property 'x' does not exist on type 'typeof A'.

This makes sense. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13252225/419956) it's shown how you need to inform the compiler of global variables, so I've tried adding...

```javascript
declare var x: any;
```

...to `module A`, but this doesn't help. I've also tried...

```javascript
declare var A.x: any;
```

...both inside and outside `module A`, but this doesn't help either.

So, how do I inform the Typescript compiler of `A.x` in a way so that I can access it safely inside `Item`?

Comment: PS. I'm very much open to edits of my question title, the "when it's declared elsewhere" is not very informative, but I had trouble coming up with a better wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add this to your TypeScript file it know that x does exist, you can also add typeinfo to this.
Because of the `declare` it won't produce any code it is just some info for the TypeScript compiler.

```
declare module A {
    var x;
}
```

You can find more info here: [Writing Definition Files](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Writing%20Definition%20Files)