# Using globally defined script inside the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am using global script declaration inside `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src='https://js.espago.com/espago-1.1.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    ...
    </head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
```

Now I want to use it inside the component.

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as $ from "jquery";

//how to import Espago?

export default class EspagoPayment extends React.Component<any, any> {
    componentDidMount() {
        $("#espago_form").submit(function(event){
             var espago = new Espago({public_key: 'xxx', custom: true, live: false, api_version: '3'});
             espago.create_token({
                    ...
             });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
                ...
        );
    }
}
```

Webpack gives an error on build.

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Espago'

How to get `Espago` visible inside the component?

Maybe there is other way to link to online js resource?

Comment: @YoannM nope `error TS2339: Property 'Espago' does not exist on type 'Window'.`

Comment: Ok... I will remove my comment to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell TypeScript that it's defined somewhere else.

```
declare var Espago: any;
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13252853/227299

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for reference.