# Using globally defined script inside the react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm creating a web based chat app using react and decided to implement end to end encryption. So I'm using signal encryption protocol. Now the main library I need to import in order to do end to end encryption is in a file called libsignal-protocol.js (it is available in signals github repo). All functions and variables I need to use is inside a variable called `libsignal` (example - `libsignal.KeyHelper.generateIdentityKeyPair()`.

Library `libsignal-protocol.js` doesn't provide javascript modules so I'm importing whole library with a global script declaration.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   <script src="libsignal-protocol.js"></script>
    ...........
   </head>
<body>
......
</body>
</html>
```

Since my chat app is a react app, I tried to call `libsignal`'s functions inside react components.

Webpack gives an error

> Line 33:13:   'libsignal' is not defined            no-undef

I googled and tried to solve this issue and found [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189882/using-globally-defined-script-inside-the-component) but that question is related with typescript and **I'm using javascript** so this is not a duplicate.

Javascript doesn't have a `declare` keyword. **How do I tell webpack that I have already imported libsignal using a global script tag?**

Comment: is your bundle being loaded before or after the libsignal library? if libsignal is putting something on global variable and your webpack bundle is being loaded afterwards you should be able to access it via `window.whateverLibSignalAddsToGlobal` . alternatively you can load the script asynchronously, and render your react tree / component afterwards https://github.com/eldargab/load-script

Comment: Thankyou! it really helped. bundle is loaded after the libsignal library. Thanks a lot. @azium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```js
window.libsignal
```

Comment: same as azium's answer in the comments.

Comment: sorry didn't notice

Comment: @IgorDoroshenko you da real mvp