# undefined error in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, model-view-controller, undefined

I saw one post on how to pass data from mvc model to .ts file suggesting to add a

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var testUrl = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.testUrl))
</script>
```

and in my .ts file I have following code which uses the testUrl

```
PerformJob(id) {
var src = `${testUrl}{id}`
fetch(src);
}
```

but when I am building with gulp I am getting error: error TS2304: Cannot find name 'testUrl'. What should I do with this undefined error in the case where the value in ts file is coming from the model? Or is there a better way to pass from model to ts instead of global param?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a Global Variable inside Typescript module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252225/call-a-global-variable-inside-typescript-module)

Answer (score -1):

```
 if (whatever != null){
//do something
} 

  else {
  alert(check value);
}
```

Unfortunately, you have two testUrl, so you first need to know which one is null

Comment: This is a) inaccurate: there's only one `testUrl` and b) doesn't answer the question, which is about typescript module scoping and c) contains a syntax error and d) is inconsistently formatted.