# TypeScript declare var error for object.property - what to do?

Tags: angular, typescript

There are many ways suggested in SO to dynamically import external scripts such as 'https://something.com/...js'  The problem is that TypeScript doesn't know about the properties so it gives errors.

As a work-around TS provides

```
declare var someObject
```

and you can put the object you retrieved from the external source in that.  This works, no errors.  However, it doesn't work for

```
let variable = someObject.property
```

The property gives an error because TS has no idea what is in your object.

Does anyone have this solved?

This is some of my actual code and it doesn't work.  The error is

```
Property createUploadWidget does not exist on type 'Scripts'
```

```
interface Scripts {
  name: string;
  src: string;
}

declare var CloudinaryScripts: Scripts;

CloudinaryScripts =
  {name: 'upLoader', src: 'https://widget.cloudinary.com/v2.0/global/all.js'};

export class CloudinaryComponent {
  ...
  private uploadWidget = CloudinaryScripts.createUploadWidget(
    {
      cloudName: ...
}
```

Also, this creates a big error:

```
CloudinaryScripts[createUploadWidget]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a Global Variable inside Typescript module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252225/call-a-global-variable-inside-typescript-module)

Comment: Not even close to a dup.

Comment: Stackblitz doesn't recognize declare.  Can't find variable: CloudinaryScripts. That error goes away if I remove declare but the problem is worse.

Comment: You are right about the array so I removed the brackets.  I've been trying many SO suggestions for importing and had an artifact left.  No change in the issue though.

Comment: This doesn't work in Angular even after the initial problem was solved.  The CloudinaryScripts in the body of the class throws a 'not defined' error when the component initializes.  It doesn't understand that the var has been declared for TypeScript. Declare doesn't work in the body of the class, it must be above it.  If I move the declaration into the body and initialize it in the constructor, OnInit, or AfterViewInit then it fails with other problems.  There doesn't seem to be a good work around but if I find one I'll add it to the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get around that error by defining it as any

```
declare var someObject: any
```

The error you are getting is correct

> Property createUploadWidget does not exist on type 'Scripts' (Only name and src exist)

```
interface Scripts {
  name: string;
  src: string;
}
```

Comment: Better than `any` would of course be to specify the actual type if it is known.

Comment: I added my actual code setup for more clarity.  I was already doing what you suggest but the question is about the property, and TS doesn't seem to have a solution other than ts ignore.  That is kind of a hack.

Comment: @Preston "and TS doesn't seem to have a solution other than ts ignore" is not correct. It provides an entire type system with which to declare the types of everything your using.

Comment: You are right and I did that yesterday as I was struggling with this.  It caused some other error with the property so I was chasing my tail and removed it.  What I didn't do is drop the array that was in the example I'm following on SO.  So your answer works.  Remove the array and have just one object AND add the property to the interface with type any and into the Script object with a value of null.  Thanks!

Comment: ```CloudinaryScripts =
  {name: 'upLoader', src: 'https://widget.cloudinary.com/v2.0/global/all.js', createUploadWidget: null};```